# Can't get my copy constructor to work in my simple code (I'm new to java)

Tags: java

Hey so I've got a simple piece of code to write, to have an output of length, height, width x2 using a copy constructor. I'm currently baffled as of what to do next since I can't figure out my issue with my copy constructor. I want my output to look something like this...

```
Package 1
input length:
input width:
input height:
package 2 
input length:
input width:
input height:
```

then I'd like to gather the input to calculate the volume (not there yet). I'm new to java and any help would be super.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Package{
private double length;
private double width;
private double height;

{
    this.length = 1.0;
    this.width = 1.0;
    this.height = 1.0;
    
}


//simple constructor
//public Package(double length, double width, double height)
public Package() {
     this.length = length;
     this.width = width;
     this.height = height;
     
 }
 
 //copy constructor
 Package(Package otherPackage) {
     this.height=otherPackage.getheight();
     this.width=otherPackage.getwidth();
     this.height=otherPackage.getheight();
     
     
 }
    public double getlength() {
        return length;
    }
    
    public void setlength(double length) {
        this.length = length;
    }   
    
    
    public double getwidth() {
        return width;
    }
    
    public void setwidth(double width) {
        this.width = width;
    }
    
        
    public double getheight() {
        return height;
    }
    
    public void setheight(double height) {
        this.height = height;
    }
    
    

    
        
        
    {


    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Package Package = new Package();
        
        System.out.println("Package 1");
        
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("inputLength");
        int Length = scan.nextInt();
        
        Scanner scan1 = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("inputWidth");
        int Width = scan1.nextInt();
        
        Scanner scan2 = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("inputHeight");
        int Height = scan.nextInt();
        
        
        
        
        
        Package Package1 = new Package();
        
        
        //System.out.println("inputWidth");
        //Scanner Width = new Scanner(System.in);
        ////System.out.println("inputHeight");
```

Answer (score 1):

Change the first line of the second constructor like this.

```
this.length=otherPackage.getlength();
```

And you should not use getters in constructor because of getter is overridable.  So

```
this.length = otherPackage.length;
```

is much better.